# Solving PDE using normal mode

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Given a linearised PDE $u_t=u_{xx}+\mu u$ where $x\in[0,1]$. A hint given is $u=V(x)\exp(st+ikx)$, where $s$ can be complex and $k$ is real.

When I substituted into the PDE, I get 
$$V''+2ikV'+(\mu+s-k^2)V=0.$$
If I assume $V=\exp(rx)$ then I get $$r^2+2ikr+\mu+s-k^2=0$$ which is a mess.

Here is what solution sheet says:
$$s=\mu-k^2$$
$$V''+k^2V=0$$
$$u=e^{(\mu-k^2)t}[C\exp(ikx)+\overline{C}\exp(-ikx)]$$
if u is real. 
I have no idea where the first two equations come from. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
u(x,t) = V(x)\mathrm{e}^{st +ikx}
$$
and
$$
u_t =u_{xx} + \mu u
$$
we find
$$
su = \left(V''\mathrm{e}^{st +ikx} +2ikV'\mathrm{e}^{st +ikx}-k^2u\right) + \mu u
$$
thus
$$
\left(V'' +2ikV'\right)\mathrm{e}^{st +ikx}+(\mu -k^2-s)u = 0
$$

This is what I would of done without the answer you have shown, make the terms in the bracket zero.
$$
\mu -k^2-s = 0 \implies s = \mu - k^2\\
V'' +2ikV' = 0
$$
thus we get
$$
\frac{V''}{V'}= \dfrac{d}{dx}\ln V'=-2ik
$$
or
$$
\ln \left(V'(x)\right) = -2ik x + C_1\implies V'(x) = C_2\mathrm{e}^{-2ik x}
$$
or finally
$$
V(x) = \frac{C_2}{-2ik}\mathrm{e}^{-2ik x} + C_3
$$
so the final general solution is
$$
u(x,t) = \left(\frac{C_2}{-2ik}\mathrm{e}^{-2ik x} + C_3\right)\mathrm{e}^{st +ikx} = \mathrm{e}^{st}\left(\frac{C_2}{-2ik}\mathrm{e}^{-ik x} + C_3\mathrm{e}^{ik x}\right)
$$
where you can label
$$
\bar{C} = \frac{C_2}{-2ik}\\
C = C_3
$$